# Some remarks about linear operators from PMA Rudin

Tags: operator-theory

> Let $L(X,Y)$ be the set of all linear transformations of the vector space $X$ into the vector space $Y$.
>   For $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$, define the *norm* $\lVert A\rVert=\sup\limits_{x: |x|\leq 1}|Ax|$.
>
> Observe that the inequality $$|Ax|\leqslant \lVert A\rVert|x|$$holds for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

**My proof:** First we have to show that $\sup\limits_{x: |x|\leq 1}|Ax|=\sup\limits_{x: |x|=1}|Ax|$.

Inequality $\sup\limits_{x: |x|\leq 1}|Ax|\geqslant\sup\limits_{x: |x|=1}|Ax|$ is obvious. But for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|x|\leq 1$ and $x\neq 0$ we have$$|Ax|=|x|\left|A\dfrac{x}{|x|}\right|\leqslant\left|A\dfrac{x}{|x|}\right|\leqslant \sup \limits_{y: |y|=1}|Ay| \qquad(\text{for $x=0$ it's also true}).$$ Hence $\sup\limits_{x: |x|\leq 1}|Ax|\leqslant\sup\limits_{y: |y|=1}|Ay|$ and in last equality we can replace $y$ by $x$. Thus $$\sup\limits_{x: |x|\leq 1}|Ax|=\sup\limits_{x: |x|=1}|Ax|.$$

Since $\lVert A\rVert=\sup\limits_{x: |x|=1}|Ax|$ then $\lVert A\rVert\geqslant|Ax|$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|x|=1$. Also $\lVert A\rVert\geqslant|A\frac{v}{|v|}|$ for all $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $\lVert A\rVert|v|\geqslant|A{v}|$ for all $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ by property of linear transformation.

Is my proof correct? Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes your proof i correct.

Comment: @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura, Thanks a lot for checking!